What is the reason of setting PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH hint to false in Hibernate
Note: My question is not about what PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH hint is in Hibernate.
In Hibernate, we have a QueryHints.PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH hint. This hint, according to docs:

Hint to enable/disable the pass-distinct-through mechanism.
A value of {@code true} enables pass-distinct-through, whereas a value of {@code false} disables it.
When the pass-distinct-through is disabled, the HQL and JPQL distinct clause is no longer passed to the SQL statement.

In understand what this hint does, I do not understand why the user would want to set
PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH to false. It seems, that the only plausible way the Hibernate can implement this feature is to apply the deduplication in-memory.
But it seems that the idea of fetching the entire result set of N records into the process memory and then applying deduplication is not that great. Why the user would want to do so?

It appears that PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH is mainly related to the Criteria API.  When set to true, Hibernate will pass the DISTINCT keyword to the underlying database.  So the deduplication happens within the SQL database, if it happens.

@TimBiegeleisen It is not what I'm asking - what is the point of setting this hint to "false"? What is the point of doing deduplication in memory?

Check out the SQL generated and the results. I can imagine that you may want distinct entities returned, but if performing a fetch join over a *:M relationship, Distinct has no value when added to the SQL. Some database might perform better without the distinct clause there in those cases.

@Chris it is not that it has no value, it is that DISTINCT in case of 1:M mapping just does not work. It does literally nothing, because the DISTINCT compares all columns in ANSI SQL. But again,  PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH is a configurable hint - why would Hibernate give the ability to configure something like this? We're missing something out.

I think you might have misunderstood my coment. By no value, I meant no value to the SQL. It is still required in the JPQL or criteria query unless you want duplicate entities returned. Since it has no value to the SQL (or functional effect on the results), and it might have some performance consequences on some databases, I believe this would be why Hibernate allows a hint to prevent it being put in the SQL. It is just speculation though - if you want the answer, go through the code to find out when it was implemented

Thanks, @Chris, I got your point. It makes sense. But it would be great to have a dedicated answer for future programmers
